# Rails 3 Polymorphic Associations, User model with multiple content items?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

In Rails 3 I'm trying to model a user content system, where the user can post different types of content, for example, note, photo, url etc.

From a Java/C# OO perspective, I would use a polymorphic relationship between the User and an interface representing a Content item, e.g. something called `IUserContent`.

I'm struggling to find an example that works how I expect it to, here's what I tried first, in short I'm getting confused about the implementation of polymorphic associations in ActiveRecord.

```
# user.rb model - includes...

has_many :notes, :as => :postable, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :postable
has_many :urls, :as => :postable, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :postable
has_many :photos, :as => :postable, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :postable


# url.rb ... 

belongs_to :postable, :polymorphic => true, :inverse_of => :urls


# photo.rb

belongs_to :postable, :polymorphic => true, :inverse_of => :photos


# note.rb

belongs_to :postable, :polymorphic => true, :inverse_of => :notes
```

I'm still just following examples I've found, and frankly this feels like User is the polymorphic target, not the content.

I think I want something like this...

```
# within user.rb

has_many :postable, :as => :postable, dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :users

# photo.rb 
# url.rb
# note.rb
# all have the following...

belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true, :inverse_of => :postable
```

... looking for a few pointers in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can do that is if all of these classes inherit from the same base class, as in:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postable, :as => :postable, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'Postable'
end

class Postable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true
end

class Photo < Postable
end

class Url < Postable
end

class Note < Postable
end
```

So, you **have** to use the ActiveRecord single-table inheritance to model such a relationship.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try, Would I need to reference the class Content anywhere? in the `has_many` for example. Just from a naming perspective, I would want to call the superclass Postable or Content and then the association based on that class name, am I way off?

Comment: Whoops, my bad, you need to set it at the **has_many :postable** definition or, instead of calling it **Content** call it **Postable**.

Comment: Oh is there anything in the DB schema that I need to cater for?

Comment: You will need to create the fields and appropriate indexes for them - http://techbot.me/2008/09/handling-database-indexes-for-rails-polymorphic-associations/